# Changing a JPanel to another JPanel doesn't repaint the change

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a main JPanel `target` in MainFraim and another `currentView` JPanel, which is added to the `target` panel. `target` panel contains buttons with listeners. These listeners are then supposed the change the content of the `curretView` panel, as demonstrated below:

```
private JPanel currentPanel;

public void setView(String type) {

    if (type.equals("overall")) {
        this.currentPanel = getOverallView();
        frame.setTitle("BookingCalendar - Overall View");
        frame.validate();
    } else if (type.equals("guest")) {
        this.currentPanel = getGuestView();
        frame.setTitle("BookingCalendar - Room View");
        frame.validate();
    } else if (type.equals("room")) {
        currentPanel.removeAll();
        this.currentPanel = getRoomView();
        frame.setTitle("BookingCalendar - Guest View");
        frame.validate();
    }
}
```

Every method I call returns new JPanel each time it is called:

```
JPanel currentPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("","20 [grow, fill] 10 [grow, fill] 20", "20 [] 10 [] 20"))
```

The problem is, whenever I call these methods, the panel won't change. It always stays the same (by default: `getOverallView()` )

I've tried with invalidate, validate, repaint on both frame, as well as the panel, but no changes occur. Could someone please elaborate more as to what I need to do in order to completely change the content of the panel `currentView`

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to add your panel to the component hierarchy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating a new JPanel() every time. Instead create one for each type of view, and use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch between them. CardLayout lets you have JPanels that get switched out like cards.

Comment: Though I haven't yet tried it, I see it as a much better solution then invoking new instance every time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just trying to move pointers around, to make the `currentView` point to a different panel. What you actually need to do is remove the `currentView` from the `target` and then add the new panel.

If this is your 2 panels...

```
JPanel target = new JPanel();
JPanel currentView = new JPanel();
```

and you add the `currentView` to the `target` like so...

```
target.add(currentView);
```

Then to change your panel, you need to remove the existing panel from the `target`, and add the new one...

```
target.remove(currentPanel);
currentPanel = new JPanel();
target.add(currentPanel);
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the -1? I think this is a perfectly valid solution to the problem the user has.

Comment: Agree. CardLayout (I think) is better, but this could work. 1+

Answer (score 1):

Also, If you don't want to use CardLayout, you can make the JPanel the new JPanel like you are doing and just call revalidate().